# Are scented natural rubber toys safe for dogs?

Tags: chewing

On the market, a lot of rubber chew toys now are being scented and I was wondering how these rubber toys are scented and whether its safe for dogs. These scented rubber chews are sold on a lot of different sites.

I recently bought a scented chew toy on Amazon, the seller claims its completely safe and the scent is not sprayed on. But when I rub my hand on the toy, the scent even gets on my hand and I am not sure if that's normal and if that's even safe for my dog.

Comment: what does the marking on the package say,have the toy been tested if so where,what is the reason for adding scent to the toy and is the rubber itself scented or is the scent added later,what type of scent is used.as you can see by my questions to you giving an answer to your question is close to impossible.

Comment: in addition to this is the toy made so the dog can not choke on the toy or get pieces off the toy.

Comment: It doesn't say how the scent was added. I even emailed the seller and all they say is it is not sprayed on and that it is 100% safe. The toy itself is quite good, the pieces don't come off and my dog is a large chewer. The thing I don't understand is a lot of different brands and a lot of online shops are all doing this scented rubber thing but they don't really explain how the rubber was scented.

Comment: i hope somebody will be able to give an answer but it might take some time,it is not common knowledge :)

Comment: @ld_pvl Could you please add a link to one or several of the products you mean? This is an international community and search result vary depending on your locale and laguage.

Comment: Vanilla scented https://fetch.co.uk/beco-pets-green-beco-bone-medium-dog-toy-88244011?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI9aj9m7fr5wIVRrDtCh1UvAYXEAQYASABEgL_GPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Vanilla scented https://www.vetuk.co.uk/dog-toys-rubber-dog-toys-c-439_699/petsafe-forever-bone-dog-chew-toy-p-42368

Comment: Mint scented https://www.amazon.co.uk/MEKEET-Rubber-Resistant-Dispensing-Cleaning/dp/B07263R1CS/ref=mp_s_a_1_9?keywords=dog+chew+toys&qid=1582590211&sprefix=Dog+chew+&sr=8-9

Comment: Milk fragrance https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B07XSNRSMS/ref=sspa_mw_detail_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzVVpXMlhERUowTVpKJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMDA5MzEyM0RYR09WNDIxREtTQyZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUExMDA4MjcxWlNPOVNTSVY1SUk2JndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfcGhvbmVfZGV0YWlsMiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdA==

Comment: My apologies for the multiple comments.